# Is the lotto draw a random experiment?

Tags: probability

I'm just starting to learn probability from scratch so please be patient.

Googling the definition of "random experiment" I came across this definition:

> A Random Experiment is an experiment, trial, or observation that can
> be repeated numerous times under the same conditions.

Then the author claims that the lotto draw is not a random experiment:

> The lotto draw is not a random experiment. This is because it cannot
> be repeated under the same conditions. The conditions are different
> because as a lotto ball is selected, it remains outside the urn. This
> decreases the number of balls inside the urn, thus changing the
> experiment.

But then there are lots of exercises on the internet asking for the probability of winning the lottery, including one on stackexchange:

[Probability lotto draw](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976021/probability-lotto-draw-exactly-one-number-divisible-by-9)

what am I missing?

Source: [What is a random experiment](https://cnx.org/contents/nAQ46U1z@3/What-is-a-Random-Experiment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book's statement about the lotto draw is technically true, but not helpful.

**Why it's true:** They're arguing that *successive draws* in an ongoing lottery are not the same thing. That is: when there are 50 balls, you have a 1/50 chance of drawing ball #7 on your first draw, and then you have a 1/49 chance of drawing ball #7 on your second draw (assuming it wasn't drawn on the first), etc.

**Why it's not helpful:** Most people usually think of "a lottery draw" as a single, indecomposable event. We don't care about ball #1 versus ball #2, for instance; we care about the full collection of all five balls that are drawn from the beginning of the lottery. And *that* process is certainly a random experiment; the collection of 5 balls drawn has the same distribution from draw to draw.

Were I the author of this book, I'd have regarded this as a bad example for illustrating the concept in question.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, within a lotto draw, the 1st extraction has not the same probability as the 2nd, which in turn is different from the 3rd, etc.

But the extracted "t-uples" (i.e. order considered) are random  equi-probable events, among different draws.